# STM32 receives weird characters as input in polling mode

Tags: embedded, stm32, uart

I am trying to play around with stm32 uart in polling mode. the transmission part is working properly and I read proper characters that I send from the MCU, however the reception part is not working properly.

```
This is a welcome message
ÿÿÿÿ
```

The first line is send from MCU to PC, the MCU then waits for reception. As I understand that `HAL_USART_Receive` is a blocking call so it should wait for user to input character from the terminal, however before i can write any characters and send them over to MCU, it moves over to the next line which is an infinite while loop. I cant understand why is it not pausing at the receive method. I debugged and checked the live expression windows, during initialization I set the receive buffer to '\0' however after passing through the HAL_Receive method the value of the buffer becomes 127. see the attached image for value stored in the buffer.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snVph.png)

Can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong. My code is shown below

```
    HAL_Init(); // Initializing HAL.

SystemClockConfig();

USART3_Init();


uint8_t tx_data[] = "This is a welcome message\r\n";
uint16_t tx_len = sizeof(tx_data);

HAL_USART_Transmit(&husart3, tx_data, tx_len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

uint8_t rx_data[5]={0};
uint16_t rx_len = sizeof(rx_data);
HAL_USART_Receive(&husart3, rx_data, rx_len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);


while(1)
{

}
```

Comment: wrong speed, wrong or word size settings.

Comment: The speed and word settings are correct, otherwise I wouldn't even receive the first line which is correct.

Comment: Did you check what is being returned from HAL_USART_Receive method? It should receive HAL_OK if the device/methond executed successfully. Check that out and comment.

Comment: yes, the return status is HAL_OK. I think i figured out the issue. I have using USART in UART mode. I had handle for USART instead of UART. However when I used UART handle it started working properly. I don't fully understand the issue as USART should also work fine in UART mode.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using the USART in UART mode (I assume you mean asynchronous mode) but your Handle (husart) is synchronous, and the HAL methods you are using are synchronous as well?

Your RX pin on your STM32 is held high which is why you get 0xFF (127) in your buffer when you call your receive function.

I think you have selected an incorrected setting in your code generator, are you using CubeIDE? If so, go to USART and choose "asynchronous" from the options and regenerate. You'll notice your handle change from husart to huart. The HAL functions for sending and transmitting are HAL_UART_Transmit() and HAL_UART_Receive(). Using these the same way in your current code will give the results you are looking for.

Comment: It looks to me as if your mixing up two things: synchronous / asynchronous function calls and synchronous / asynchronous USART mode. For function calls, the difference is blocking vs non-blocking calls, the latter ones using interrupts and DMA. For USART mode, the difference is whether a clock signal is used in addition to RX and TX.

Comment: variable name makes no difference. It can be even called spi. to activate additional clock signal you simply add it to the configuration structure

Comment: if I use USART in UART mode, then theoretically there should be no difference between UART module and USART module. both should work similarly.

Comment: Also, I am not using auto code generation, I am writing my code manually

Comment: Apologies, I assumed you were using a code generator because of the HAL functions.
Can I see your USART_Init() function then please?

Comment: Also you are correct, but when using the HAL theres different types and function calls when using USART in UART mode. 
e.g. you use UART_HandleTypeDef not USART_HandleTypeDef.